# Sequelize 1:n relation always empty array

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

There is a 1:n relationship between `project` and `stats`. A project can have multiple stats.

```
// Project model definition
const Project = sequelize.define('Project', {
    // table columns...
  }, {
  freezeTableName: true,
});
Project.associate = (models) => {
  models.Project.hasMany(models.Stats, { as: 'stats', foreignKey: 'projectId', sourceKey: 'id' });
};
```

and

```
// Stats model definition
const Stats = sequelize.define('Stats', {
  // ...
  projectId: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    references: {
      model: 'Project',
      key: 'id'
    }
  },
  // ...
}, {
  freezeTableName: true,
  timestamps: false
});
```

And when I try to query a single project with its stats:

```
models.Project.findByPk(req.params.projectId, {
  include: [
    {
      model: models.Stats, as: 'stats', where: { id: models.sequelize.col('project.id') }, required: false
    }
  ]
}).then((project) => {
  // project.get().stats always an empty array
})
```

`project.get().stats` always an empty array. But when I catch the SQL generated by Sequelize and execute it by myself, the query is working as expected (result has multiple rows because of multiple stats for the project).

Could you please tell me what is wrong with my relationship definitions?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for `where` condition, you can simply do that by this :

```
models.Project.findByPk(req.params.projectId, {
  include: [
    {
      model: models.Stats, as: 'stats', 
      required: false
    }
  ]
}).then((project) => {
  // project.get().stats // Check now
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately `project.get().stats` is still empty array. And yes I'm sure data actually exist.